# Does Cas Server 4.0.0 have LDAP server by itself or not?

Tags: ldap, cas

I have been working on single sign on CAS system to connect my web apps together using CAS LDAP. But do i have to use open LDAP and configure it with my CAS server or by default CAS servers do have a built in LDAP services? If they do have I'm currently using CAS server 4.0.0 and I'm looking for LDAP configs separated below in commas.
 LDAP bind DN, LDAP bind password, Base DN, Username filter attribute, Search attributes.
Does anybody knows the value must be filled for the above CAS LDAP configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in LDAP server in CAS.